# Scapy run time error, ValueError: Unknown pypcap network interface

Tags: python, scapy

I have not understood for several hours
why this code does not work, I went through
all the versions of Python and created a
virtual environment.

Help ?

Thanks in advance

```py
from scapy.all import ARP, Ether, srp

target_ip = "192.168.43.*"

arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip)
ether = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
packet = ether/arp

result = srp(packet, timeout=3)
clients = []

for sent, received in result:
    clients.append({'ip': received.psrc, 'mac': received.hwsrc})
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\arpp\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 772, in pcapname
    return IFACES.dev_from_name(dev).pcap_name
  File "C:\Users\user\arpp\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 696, in dev_from_name
    raise ValueError("Unknown network interface %r" % name)
ValueError: Unknown network interface '\\Device\\NPF_Loopback'
```

Comment: Make sure you have installed npcap

Comment: I have Wireshark actually and npcap, soo i dont get why it dosnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed npcap and its work just fine !!!